# c++ Checking if a directory exists in Unix and call void function if it exists.

Tags: c++, unix, directory

So I'm trying to implement linux command rm -rf and in my main i have something like:

```
struct stat sb;
if(unlink(argv[i]) == 0)
{
    printf (argv[i]); printf(" Deleted\n");
}
if (S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode))
{   
    remove_dir(argv[i]);
}
else 
{
    perror(argv[i]);
}
```

What I am trying to do is that if the user input is directory, then call the void remove_dir(); to delete the directories, but instead it just prints whether argv[i] is directories or not. Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: You never did anything to populate `sb`, so I would imagine the chances of `sb.st_mode` dictating a is-directory state to be completely random chance (and undefined behavior, since the content is *indeterminate*).

Answer (score 1):

You need to populate `struct stat sb` using the function `stat`:

```
struct stat sb;
if (stat(argv[i], &sb) != 0) 
{
    perror(argv[i]);
}
```

Then, and only then, can you use `S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode)`.